# ASP.NET MVC 3 Application Not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im passing the URL like "`http://localhost:6384/Name/4:`" But this is get an error.

**Controller Method :**

```
//
// GET: /Name/5
        public string SetName(int id)
        {
            return "You entered: " + id;
        }
```

**Error:**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.

Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0
```

Please Help Me!!!

Comment: Your URL is /Name/ but unless you've created a specific route for this, it should be /SetName/ as that's the method name. If that doesn't work for you, you can add a route in the global.asax for /{action}/{id}. I can't remember the syntax offhand but that's an option.

Answer (score 2):

Verify following steps,

1) In global.axas verify the default root as follows,

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

2) Mention controller name in the url , if you controller and action is as follows

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult SetName(int id)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }
    }
```

then url will be ,

```
http://localhost:6384/Home/SetName/4
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public ActionResult SetName(int id) {
        return Content("You entered: " id);
    }
```

Sorry, it was easier than that. You're entering the URL incorrect. You have not specified the controller name.

http://localhost:6384/CONTROLLERNAME/SetName/4

Answer (score 0):

In this error message.
HTTP Status 400 Bad Request - Bad Syntax

Possibly, because the Action Result cannot found or not exist.

This is wrong action method:

```
// GET: /Name/5
public string SetName(int id)
{
   return "You entered: " + id;
}
```

I will correct your action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Setname(int id)
{
   ViewBag.Result = "You entered: " + id;

    return View();
}
```